# IntelliJ "Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS)" plugin is not available

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14

I'm trying to add RESTful support to my IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2.

According to JetBrains' documentation, "Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS)" plugin should do the work, but it is not available in plugins list. See [JetBrains' instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/preparing-for-rest-development.html).

Does anybody have an idea about IDEA?

Comment: Is the project you're working on a Java EE project?

Comment: I did not create the project yet. Yes, I'd like to create project with these instructions:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/preparing-for-rest-development.html

Comment: check this documentation `https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/preparing-for-rest-development.html`

Comment: also check this video www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3nnjmK1GwE

Comment: That is exactly what I use. The say to install "Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS)" plugin.
The problem is that the plugin is just not there.

Comment: at the very beginning of doc mentioned `This plugin is bundled with IntelliJ IDEA and enabled by default.`, so i think you go with the steps in the doc and check again

Comment: Then I should see the plugin in enabled plugins list, but I do not see it at all

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition or IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate?

Comment: I use community edition

Comment: yole, could it be, that this plugin is not available for community edition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I found at IntelliJ website, Java EE is supported by Ultimate edition only.
I used the Community edition :(

Now I switch this project to Eclipse...

Comment: I'm growing tired of intellij